# Tampermonkey Java Script insert and run in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have a Javascript for a specific website in Chrome.
Now i want this Script to automatically get insert and start in my chrome console via Tampermonkey.

So everyone the page gets loaded i want to run the Script automatically!

Can you help me?

Comment: Isn't that pretty much the very goal of TamperMonkey? Automatically run a script on a given website? Did you read the doc?

Comment: Please try something first, and then comeback with your research, what have you tried and what don't work as expected

Comment: In console my script works well but when insert in TM nothing happens…. I am a beginner and just need help. Please be nice

Comment: We are being nice :) So did you read the doc or not? All we know is that "it doesn't work". Nothing else. You didn't provide your script, nor what you did exactly in TamperMonkey, how you implemented it, the rules you applied, etc. You're just saying, "I did something and it didn't work". Sooooooo... yeah, it's a little hard to say exactly how to fix that!